# Still required to turn Remember me off when migrating from 2.5 to 3.x?

Tags: maintenance, joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, migration

With 3.3 and 3.2.4 is it still required to turn the plugin Remember me off? What is the technical reason?

Comment: I didn't know that, where did you hear that?

Comment: It is advice given on forum.joomla.org. See http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=710&t=825407 as an example.

Comment: @jackJoe It's quite common: [Fatal error when updating joomla from 3.1.1 to 3.2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689666/fatal-error-when-updating-joomla-from-3-1-1-to-3-2-2/21694976#21694976)

Comment: Indeed, only that is after the update went wrong. The advice to turn off makes the update succeed, if there are no other problems offcourse. A failed update might leave you in limbo, very difficult to recover from it.

Comment: I had that issue on a couple of upgrades 3.1 up and was happy I had a backup and mysql access to stop them being totally locked in white screen crash

Answer (score 6):

To answer 'what is the technical reason', I took a look through the tracker and GitHub notes. The issue seems to be two-fold - a failure to delete certain files during the upgrade, and failure to apply certain SQL updates. However, if only affects some and not others. See the [bug tracker](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_id=8103&tracker_item_id=32568) for additional info.

The general best practice option approach seems to be:

*If not already borked...*

- Backup!
- Disable `System -> Remember Me`  plugin
- Do the update
- Enable `System -> Remember Me`  plugin

*If borked and no backup...*

> When the install fails on url /administrator/index.php?option=com_joomlaupdate&task=update.finalise with php  error '\plugins\system\remember\remember.php on line 94'
>
> Running \cli\deletefiles.php from the command line then refreshing the /administrator/index.php?option=com_joomlaupdate&task=update.finalise gives FULL SUCCESS

[This commit](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/3467) ostensibly fixes the issue, but suggest it's to do with `$this->app` not being prepopulated by the system. It may also be worth a look if the above fails. Keep in mind this is quite a recent pull request (16th April 2014) and hasn't been approved in the tracker: YMMV.

Comment: Amazingly I completely fell into this trap moments ago. The answer definitely works :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem only appears on certain servers, for reasons I don't yet know exactly.
On my servers it works without issues, but a friend had this problem as well.

I have done a PR which I believe will solve the issue, see https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/3467. If someone who has this problem can test this patch and see if it fixes the issue, then that would be great :-)