# Is it possible to upgrade Joomla 2.5 to 3.4 without losing data?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, upgrade

I was wondering if there's any way to upgrade my Joomla 2.5 website, with VM2 and a template for Joomla 2.5, to Joomla 3.
Downloading afterwards the same template and some other plugins and components for that version...

Comment: You won't lose any data, however be sure to take a backup of your current 2.5 site before starting the update

Comment: What about if I use a Joomla 2.5 template on Joomla 3...?

Comment: A few errors will most likely be thrown which could be fixed, but it might be easier to download the Joomla 3.x compatible version of your template

Comment: You should setup a local dev environment and try it. Making use of Akeeba Backup. If you ancounter issues post them and we will try help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is very frequent. At this time, you can find many answers. Just do your research to find the best answer for you.

For instance, this is one of the possible answers: [Upgrade from 2.5 to 3.x overview](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1158/upgrade-from-2-5-to-3-x-overview)