# Trying to update gantry package, get this error

Tags: gantry

I am following ine previous instructions to upgrade from 2.5.x to 2.5.28 in preparation to upgrade to 3.5.  Install, DB steps went fine. 2 package updates were fine, but when I try to do Gantry to 4.1.33, whether through update or install, it throws this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method JInstallerPackage::getManifest() in /home1/someuser/public_html/joomlatest/tmp/install_599de020ec6ed/install.php on line 75
```

Comment: Post your issue at rocketheme support forum.

Comment: Rocketheme support forum seems to only be available for paid subscriptions.  The site I am working on is for a non-profit club with very limited budget.

Comment: I have the same issue...have you found any solution?
Thanks

Comment: This question is also asked at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45862812/1983389

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [the last version of Gantry 4 that is supported on Joomla 2.5 is v4.1.32](http://www.rockettheme.com/forum/gantry-solved-threads/272109-solved-updating-gantry-fatal-error).

You can download Gantry v4.1.32 from:

http://gantry4.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/gantry_joomla_framework-4.1.32.zip

Upgrade to Gantry v4.1.32, [migrate your Joomla 2.5 website to Joomla 3.x](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/18953/120) and then upgrade to the latest version of Gantry 4.