# Migrating Joomla 2.5 site to 3.3

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, migration

I have been asked to migrate a site using Joomla 2.5 to a GoDaddy hosting account. On this account I can only use the latest version of Joomla. Are there any major problems I will run into or is it simply a case of;

1. FTP file structure to new hosting account
2. Import MySQL database
3. Change *configuration.php*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there shouldn't be any problems. The only thing you will need to do is make some changes to the **configuration.php** so that the database setting match your database on the GoDaddy account.

You may however some some issues with some extensions. In an ideal world, if the extensions you're using have been developed using the most up to date coding standards, then there will only be some deprecated code, which should not affect functionality. However, I've seen lots of extensions for Joomla 2.5, that use Joomla 1.5 coding standard and this is what will cause issues. It does occur sometimes with big complex extensions such as jDownloads, and they do not provide a stable Joomla 3.x compatible version, thus you would have to find an alternative.

Due to this, be sure to keep a backup of your Joomla 2.5 site and I would suggest migrating on a test server, not the live site, to ensure that everything works smoothly.

Comment: Thank you for the information, is there any way i can check which extensions will cause me problems before i place the site on the server?

Comment: In regards to coding, you can by looking through the code and reading the Joomla API, however this could take weeks. You would be best off putting the site on a test server, migrating to Joomla 3.x, doing to the developer site for each extensions to see if there is a Joomla 3.x compatible version, install it if so, else check to see if it works as expected.

Comment: You could also load a clean install of Joomla 3.x and then install all the extensions new one by one from the JED site. this way you would first see if they worked with new version before you added the old data as you will probably have to check both parts and so good to do in isolation.

Comment: You're more than welcome...good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

There are database differences between Joomla 2.5 and 3.3. So importing a MySQL dump from a 2.5 site into a 3.3 site will give you some troubles for sure.

Best way to migrate is using the inbuilt Joomla updater. Change the udpate stream in the options to "STS" and it will offer you to upgrade to 3.3.
This will make all the needed file and database changes for you.

You will more than likely need a new template and some extensions may be not compatible (check with the extension developer site).

To move the site from one host to another, you can use Akeeba Backup to make a backup and restore it on the target host.
You can also use that software to restore the Joomla 2.5 site on a localhost and do the upgrade locally. Thus not risking to break the existing site :)

Answer (score 0):

It is worth also doing this check to turn Remember Me off
[Still required to turn Remember me off when migrating from 2.5 to 3.x?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/244/still-required-to-turn-remember-me-off-when-migrating-from-2-5-to-3-x?rq=1)

And probably turning off all added non core extensions and then back on one by one as you update them.